# Is the button tag the same as input = submit?

Tags: html

Does number 1 have the same effect as number 2? I am new to HTML

1)

```
<input type="submit" value="Google">
```

2. 

```
<button>Google</button>
```

Comment: `type="submit"` is generally used to submit the forms, and refreshes the page on click, while normal button when clicked does not refresh the page

Comment: @NikhilSingh — What does that have to do with the question? `type="submit"` is the **default** for `<button>` elements. There is no mention of `type="button"`